# SSRS connection string Encryption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs

i am working on porject to encrypt the connection between ssrs reports and sql server. we have already installed ssl certificate on sql server. can i know how to encrypt the connection string in SSRS datasource

Answer (score 2):

When you setup a [data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/manage-report-data-sources?view=sql-server-ver15), you can specify components of the connection string directly.

Simply add the following to the connection string:

`Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True`

That will force encryption between the SQL Server and the SSRS reporting server for the given data source.  Any report that uses that data source will obtain its data via an encrypted channel.  The `TrustServerCertificate=True` tells the client (SSRS) to trust the server certificate, even if it's a self-generated, or untrusted, certificate.

Comment: Thanks . i tried this but i am getting the  error "The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted data in the database"

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203955/the-report-server-was-unable-to-validate-the-integrity-of-encrypted-data